# Automatic replacement of strings in gedit

Tags: string, replace, gedit

I want to replace some strings defined by me in `gedit`, after a word has been completed and/or the document has been saved. For example `\ðrac` should be replaced with `\frac`

How do I do this in `gedit` or with a plugin for `gedit`?

If it is not possible in `gedit`, then I'm happy for suggestions of other programs that has the feature with the same basic feature set as `gedit`.